# How to create custom branching logic in app survey in sharepoint 2013?

Tags: survey, nintex

I'm tring create custom  branching logic in sharepoint 2013:
[image]

The user selects several items in the list and depending on which categories he chooses, he will receive groups of questions corresponding to the categories